# Why does the audio to my bluetooth speaker always stutter

Tags: sound, bluetooth

Trying to use a BT speaker (MOVE c1655) - pairs ok - selects in settings but
the audio is always a slow stuttering stream.  I've researched this but not finding a solution nor any consistent problem descriptions.

PC is an AZW Z83V miniPC Intel ATOM 64 bit

OS is Linuxium-atom-ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso

"stuttering audio stream" is always BT only (if I cable the speaker to the PC
the audio is without issue).

Have tried WIFI off - Internet stream via ethernet only - same issue

Have tried audio files stored on the PC - internet eliminated - same issue

Because cabling the speaker (not using it's BT) shows good audio, I don't suspect it's an ALSA vs PULSEAUDIO issue but am open to ideas.

Have tried CLI speaker-test - same issue

Is there a way to change the streaming settings for something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have z83v x5-x8350 atom.

But audio of z83v dont work with ubuntu 16.04 lts

Then My question is
Did you install something else to make the audio work?

Comment: Claudio the distro I'm using is Linuxium-atom-ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso      It seems that the people behind Linuxium are working hard to make these Atom PC's work.   I just noticed on their site that they're showing the newest version Ubuntu 18.04 and am going to try that.